# How to get sender name in message from quickblox in JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, quickblox

I have integrated quickblox into my app, I want a name of sender in message

scenario :

currently, I am getting all messages from dialog using dialog id, when I got the message I want to add the name of sender into my message header. like

```
Mayur (Name of sender) 10:00 PM

Good to go (Message)
```

Can quickblox provide any way to do like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by getting all users ids from dialogs.

```
Retrieve all Users

var params = { page: '1', per_page: '100'};

QB.users.listUsers(params, function(err, users){
  if (users) {
    // success
  } else {
    // error
  }
});
```

Using this function to get all users details from the particular dialog.